# Do Specialties gained from Command Packages, and Sophont types count against the upper limit?

Tags: planet-mercenary

One of the rules in Planet Mercenary is that, when you're buying Skill Specialties, you can't have more Specialties than you have ranks in that Skill. Some Command Packages and Sophont types offer built-in Specialties. I noticed that the Esspererin have the Flight (Athletics) specialty, but no inherent ranks in Athletics, which suggests that maybe these built-in specialties don't count against that upper limit (since otherwise, an Esspererin without at least one rank in Athletics is in violation of the character creation rules).

I have asked the question in the [Planet Mercenary Facebook group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/1445604298891148/), where the creator occasionally offers clarification from on high, but I figured I'd also post it here so that it's available in a more public forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was fast.

[image: Specialty Clarification from Alan Bahr]

> **Me** In the process of inputting the Planet Mercenary character creation rules into Herolab (I basically have everything except AI rules, custom weapons, and attaching the mercenaries to the same central Company), I came upon an interesting wrinkle. The Esspererin have the Flight (Athletics) Specialty, but no inherent ranks in Athletics. Normally, you need ranks in a Skill to get Specialties...
>
> Which I guess leads to the question, do you guys include "built-in" specialties against the number of specialties that can be attached to a skill based on its rank?
>
> **Alan Bahr** Yes. :)
>
> **Me** So, an Esspererin who has not spent at least one rank in Athletics can't use the Specialty? And has to buy at least two ranks if he wants another Specialty? Or is it just the latter?
>
> **Alan Bahr** Just the latter.
>
> **Alan Bahr** No ranks doesn't stop you from rolling a skill check with +0. The skill check still allows for specialties.